# What exactly do these functions do? I new to MEAN stacks and im just trying to understanding what mongojs is doing in these lines of code

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mongojs

Please just help clarify whats happening inside these two function. I'm a bit more comfortable with mongoose as well. If you can provide a mongoose a equivalent that would be great as well.

```
router.put('/api/todos', function (req, res){
    db.todos.update({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body._id)
    }, {
        isCompleted: req.body.isCompleted,
        todo:req.body.todo
    }, {}, function (err, data){
        res.json(data);
    });
});

router.delete('/api/todos/:_id', function (req, res){
    db.todos.remove({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params._id)}, '',
        function (err, data){
            res.json(data);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

`router.put('/api/todos', function (req, res){
    db.todos.update({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.body._id)
    }, {
        isCompleted: req.body.isCompleted,
        todo:req.body.todo
    }, {}, function (err, data){
        res.json(data);
    });
});`

This takes the request body from a `PUT` request to `/api/todos`. It ues the `_id` from the request body to find a document in MongoDB and sets `isCompleted` to the value of `isCompleted` from the request body and `todo` to the value of `todo` from the request body. When the update completes, it sends the resultant object as a json response.

`router.delete('/api/todos/:_id', function (req, res){
    db.todos.remove({
        _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params._id)}, '',
        function (err, data){
            res.json(data);
        });
    });`

This takes a `DELETE` request to `/api/todos/{some id}`, deletes the corresponding document in Mongo, and returns what that document was to the client.